# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib' with jupyter notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow2.0

So this is my error [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib']

I'm using tensorflow 2.0.0 and python 3.6.9 when i downgrade the tensorflow version of the code doesn't work when i upgrade it the same thing happens . (i am using jupyter notebook)

I tried to downgrade tensorflow's version and vice versa .

[This is the part of the code where i have the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIt22.png)

Please help i really can't find a solution.

Comment: According to [this answer](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31350#issuecomment-518749548) tensorflow.contrib doesn't exist in TF 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tensorflow.contrib is being removed in version 2.0, you therefore need version <= 1.14 to operate tflearn.

In the command line (not the notebook), `conda install tensorflow=1.14` (or tensorflow-gpu=1.14 if you want GPU support ; or pip install rather than conda install depending on what you are used to do).

Answer (score 0):

tensorflow.contrib is being removed in version 2.0, you therefore need version <= 1.14 to operate tflearn (by the way, this is a TFlearn issue, not a tensorflow one).

In your case, I would consider moving to tensorflow (instead of tflearn) and using the tf.keras API, which provides the higher-level API tflearn aimed at offering in times when tf.keras was not out yet.